# Проверьте пожалуйста СПП! Спасибо!

Tags: синтаксис

(1) Он ждал этого дня, **как никто на свете не мог бы ждать ничего и никого**: ни на миг не падая духом. (СПП сравнения?)

(2) Конечно, можно было придумать множество достойных оправданий тому, что его экипаж простаивает перед дверью сеньориты Линч, но придумывать можно было не долго, во всяком случае, не столько, **сколько бы ему хотелось**: всю жизнь. (СПП степени?)

(3) А тут они были высказаны просто и точно, **как ей самой хотелось бы высказать их**. (СПП сравнения?)

(4) Однако он не мог выказать своего отношения, **как хотел бы**, ибо сердце сыграло с ним злую шутку. (СПП степени?)

Comment: (1) Она вдруг обнаружила, что думает о нем гораздо чаще и гораздо более заинтересованно, чем ей хотелось бы. (СПП сравн.?) 
(2) Она почти все время на ногах и держалась великолепно, так, как если бы слушала оперу. (если судить по корреляту "так", то должны быть СПП обр. действ., но и сравн. присутствует) 
(3) Oна вошла в кабинет мужа, вопреки обычаю и даже вопреки своему желанию, словно это была не она, а другая, поступавшая так, как сама она не поступила бы никогда на свете. (здесь меня интересует та часть с сосл. накл. СПП обр. действ.?)

Comment: Разбор предложений во втором ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня вызывает сомнение отнесенность некоторых предложений к придаточным сравнительным. В современной грамматике выделяется тип местоименно-относительных  СПП, построенных по схеме "коррелят в главной части - союзное слово в придаточной". Это **общая** схема для придаточных определительных, образа действия. степени и т.д., которые являются **частными** вариантами этого общего типа.

Коррелят в таких предложениях **обязателен** в литературной речи, но достаточно часто **пропускается в разговорной**, но при этом может быть восстановлен. Возможно, что часть предложений можно отнести именно к такому виду СПП.

В то же время эти предложения по структуре близки к придаточным сравнительным, **когда сравниваются две ситуации**. Мне кажется. что **различать их надо по законченности ситуации,** описанной в главном предложении, тогда придаточное является сравнительным. Если же требуется дополнить главное предложение обстоятельством, то придаточное выступает в роли такого обстоятельства и имеет значение образ действия.

**ОТВЕТЫ (с учетом сказанного)**

(1) Он ждал этого дня (так), как никто на свете не мог бы ждать ничего и никого: ни на миг не падая духом. Придаточное образа действия, коррелят ТАК пропущен.

(2) Конечно, можно было придумать множество достойных оправданий тому, что его экипаж простаивает перед дверью сеньориты Линч, но придумывать можно было **не долго**, во всяком случае, **не столько**, **сколько** бы ему хотелось: всю жизнь. Придаточное образа действия (точнее, может быть, длительности действия).

(3) А тут они были высказаны просто и точно, как ей самой хотелось бы высказать их.  А это похоже на придаточное сравнительное (достоверное сравнение), в таких придаточных сравнивают ситуации. Например: Она гладила рукопись **ласково**, как гладят любимую кошку.

(4) Однако он не мог выказать своего отношения (так), как хотел бы, ибо сердце сыграло с ним злую шутку. Придаточное образа действия (как?), коррелят ТАК пропущен.

Comment: Вера, спасибо большое!!! У меня нашлись в анализе еще три предложения с сомнениями. Не смогли бы Вы на них взглянуть пожалуйста? Здесь уже символы не позволяют, поэтому добавлю к общему вопросу наверху...

Answer (score 2):

Согласна со всеми, кроме последнего. В придаточных меры и степени, как и в образа действия обязательны указательные слова,а здесь их нет, следовательно, это придат. сравнения

Answer (score 1):

(1) Она вдруг обнаружила, что думает о нем гораздо чаще и гораздо **более заинтересованно, чем** ей хотелось бы.

Это прикомпаративное придаточное, разновидность сравнительного. Грамматическая модель:  сравнит. степень прилаг,, наречия/ союз ЧЕМ. От классического сравнительного придаточного  оно отличается по структуре: это присловное придаточное в нерасчлененном  СПП, а обычные СПП со сравнительными придаточными являются расчлененными.

(2) Она почти все время на ногах и держалась **великолепно, так, как если бы** слушала оперу. 
Это СПП с двойным значением (обстоятельство образа действия + предположительное сравнение ), общий тип СПП – местоименно-союзный. Кроме того, в структуре предложения присутствует уточнение: «великолепно, так, как если бы…».

(3) «….поступавшая **так, как** сама она **не** поступила **бы** никогда на свете.
Здесь местоименно-соотносительный тип СПП (поступавшая так/как), но ситуация в придаточном недостоверная, с отрицанием, поэтому используется сослагательное наклонение.

Comment: спасибо большое! =)